# Transaction tear-off

Tags: corda

I am using Corda and in one of our use-cases, we need to limit the transaction information shared among the nodes (e.g. 4 parties) in the network.

The transaction state will contain sensitive data of other nodes but we need to limit this data to be accessed by authorised parties only. e.g. party A should not see data of Party B in the transaction state.

I looked at the Corda documentation and tumbled upon Transaction tear-off but I could not find any concrete implementation of this.

I would be really grateful, if someone can give me an examples of transaction tear-off implementation or point me to right direction if there is better approach to limit transaction state sharing among parties than using transaction tear-off.

Thanks in advance

Comment: to understand clearly there are 4 nodes in your network (ABCD)
and you want transaction to happen between A and B and don't want C and D to know about it? or you want some data to be seen by party B to sign the tx?

Comment: The transaction state will be carried out by 5th node and the outputstate will be shared with the ABCD nodes but we want to limit the data sharing among the ABCD for that specifc output state coming from 5th node.

Answer (score 1):

Transaction tear-offs are typically used in the use case where you're using an oracle to attest to a fact within your transaction.

The idea being, you want to strictly limit the oracle to viewing only what is required in order for it to attest, so you filter out all other parts of the transaction.

Take a look at the following tutorial https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-tear-offs.html it contains the steps required to create a filtered transaction.

You can also take a look at the samples on https://www.corda.net/samples that make use of an oracle. In particular, if you look at the Options sample, the OptionIssueFlow creates a filtered transaction for the oracle to sign.

One other approach - would it matter if Party A could see the data of Party B if it didn't know it was Party B? If not, you could look at using confidential identities https://docs.corda.net/api-identity.html#confidential-identities